# Hiding a checkbox and creating a custom button

Tags: html, css

I am trying to hide checkbox, but still allow it to check when a div / button is pressed.
My code for the custom buttons are

```
<div class="checkbox flex item  center-text  bg-theme" 
style="border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;border-radius: 12px;">
<i class="twf twf-round-pushpin"></i> 
<label for="nearest" class ="color-theme right-5">Nearest to me </label>
<input type="checkbox" id="nearest" class = "filtering" value="nearest" >
```

I've tried adding `visibility:none` and `display:none;` but this just doesn't work, when i click the buttons, nothing happens.

Comment: Where's the checkbox?

Comment: Do you have any JavaScript linked up to these elements? What is `filter-type`?

Comment: where is checkbox?

Comment: whoops have re edited

Comment: try with `opacity:0`

Answer (score 0):

You might try to add `opacity:0;` in the css.
If you do not want the box to be directly checkable, use `pointer-events:none` in addition to that

Comment: issue is, when i put opacity:0 , it still leaves a big space where the checkbox would be, so want to cover that up also

Comment: @JamieWarren try using `transform:scale(0);`

Comment: nope, this makes the button do nothing when clicked

Comment: @JamieWarren Does it even work if the checkbox is visible ?

Comment: yeah it does, even if you click the label / button it checks the checkbox

Comment: try setting the width and height to 0

Answer (score 0):

Add `display:inline-block` on the first `div` so it will take only the minimum place and won't leave a big blank.

Then for the checkbox, using `display:none` works fine, I've added an `onclick` callback to log the state of the checkbox on each click on the label.

Try this sample:

```html
<div class="checkbox flex item  center-text  bg-theme" style="border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;border-radius: 12px; display:inline-block;">
    <i class="twf twf-round-pushpin"></i> 
    <label for="nearest" class ="color-theme right-5">Nearest to me </label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="nearest" class = "filtering" value="nearest"  style="display: none;" onclick="console.log(this.checked)">
</div>
```